# How do I copy a folder keeping owners and permissions intact?

Tags: command-line

So I was going to back up my home folder by copying it to an external drive as follows:

```
sudo cp -r /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

With the result that all folders on the external drives are now owned by `root:root`. How can I have `cp` keep the ownership and permissions from the original?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `-p` flag.

```
-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
       preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Note that for the permissions to be correctly replicated, the destination file system should be the same as the source file system. In other words, your external drive should be formatted as `ext4` if, as is usually the case, your home folder is stored on a partition of that type.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with this command. Permissions looks right but owner is wrong. It does not copy origin owner and set up current user as owner. What is wrong?
`cp -r -p  /var/www/xxx.com/ /var/www/xxx.com-backup`

Answer (score 13):

You can use the -p flag:
`cp -rp /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home`
or use rsync command line:
`rsync -aux /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home`

Answer (score 9):

Use `sudo cp -a /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home`, it will recurse into subdirs and preserve all file attributes.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with this command. Permissions looks right but owner is wrong. It does not copy origin owner and set up current user as owner. What is wrong? cp -a  /var/www/xxx.com/ /var/www/xxx.com-backup

Answer (score 3):

Older answers above would put the folder 'my_home' into the my_home folder on the destination
resulting in /media/backup/my_home/my_home/child_stuff

so this might be better:

```
sudo cp -a /home/my_home/. /media/backup/my_home
```

the '/.' on the source copies the contents and includes hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked well for me :

```
sudo rsync -a /home/my_home/ /media/backup/my_home/
```

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43611

Comment: Do you mean `-A`? Lowe case `-a` is archive while upper case `-A` is preserve ACLs