# Recovered /usr/bin folder - Problem with permissions

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, recovery-mode

I accidentally deleted my `/usr/bin/` folder on my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu server. Luckily I had a backup. Its a little bit old, but not much changed since then. I thought I could just copy the old bin from the backup, which is in another computer, to the SD-Card from my raspberry.

It worked, ubuntu server is working again. Sudo is not. I suppose because I created the new bin on another computer (another user) the permissions are all messed up. It brings the following error:

```
/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

How can I restore the standard permissions for `/usr/bin`? Can I do this without logging out and login again as root? ([deleted all the files in usr/bin typing in rm -rf *](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191942/deleted-all-the-files-in-usr-bin-typing-in-rm-rf)) Because I don't know how to do this in ubuntu server. I'm accessing my server over ssh.

Do I have to reinstall the packages like this?

```
apt-get --reinstall install $(grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//')
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm answering my question myself. I like this. You search, try and learn something.

The trick is to copy the permissions with the file. I actually learned this searching for how to backup my server. Great video by the way:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTayZIou-1M

I realised that you can copy the original permissions with the files, leaving them intact. And here is how: [How do I copy a folder keeping owners and permissions intact?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165998/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact)

So I just:

sudo cp -rp backup/usr/bin SD-card/usr/bin

from my other computer with the backup to the raspberry SD-card.

Now with this knowledge I will try to restore my complete system from the backup files. Just to have a clean system again.

Wish me luck. ;)